# Local Storage multiple fields with one field overwriting the second

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am creating a Chrome extension that restricts off-limits TV content. I have two roll-down menu forms that store values to Local Storage.

**Javascript (external files):**

**ratings.js**

```
window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementById('saveRatings').onsubmit=saveRatings;
}

function saveRatings() {
    var selectedRatings = document.forms["ratings_form"]["ratings"].value;

// store selectedRatings to local storage
    localStorage.storedRatings = selectedRatings;

}
```

**age.js**

```
window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementById('saveAge').onsubmit=saveAge;
}

function saveAge() {
    var selectedAge = document.forms["age_form"]["age"].value;

// store selectedAge to local storage
    localStorage.storedAge = selectedAge;

}
```

**HTML**

```
                    <summary>Select Content to Allow</summary><br>
                        <form name = "ratings_form" id="saveRatings">
                        <select name="ratings" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="G">G only</option>
                            <option value="G/PG">G/PG only</option>
                            <option value="G/PG/PG13">G/PG/PG-13 only</option>
                            <option value="G/PG/PG13/R">G/PG/PG-13/R</option>
                        </select>
                        <div></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save">  </form>

                        <summary>Select Age Group to Deter</summary><br>
                        <form name = "age_form" id="saveAge">
                        <select name="age" multiple="multiple">
                            <option value="e">Everyone</option>
                            <option value="ct">Children & Teens;</option>
                            <option value="c">Children</option>
                            <option value="0">Turn off</option>
                        </select>
                        <div></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save">
                        </form>
```

The key-value pair for age_form stores correctly. However, ratings_form always gives me undefined. If I switch up the order (age first and ratings next), then the key-value pair for ratings_form would give me the correct value whereas age_value would give me undefined. It seems like the second form values are overwriting the first form values. How can I prevent this overwriting from occurring.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, your problem is that you're overwriting the window.onload function with whichever code runs last! All you need is a simple `console.log();` in each function to see that the first one is not being called. You can remedy this with `addEventListener()` or by using jQuery's `$(document).ready()`.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('1');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('2');
});
```

Just remember `onload` is a property of `window` and acts just like any variable/property would. Consider this:

```
var foo = 'bar';
foo = 'baz';
console.log(foo); // displays 'baz', of course! You changed the value!
```

That is just what you did with the onload function. You changed it to something else.

Comment: localStorage.foo and localStorage.getItem('foo') will both work.  The only difference is getItem will return an null if foo doesn't exist where dot or array notion will result in undefined.

Comment: Hmm. I probably read some fail tutorial on it :( I remember reading that set/get were the appropriate method...dunno why that was said. Nor do I know why they even bother with them if they aren't needed. I don't see anything wrong with this code then, other than it's just not following other good practices (global mess).

Comment: @dc5 found the issue. He didn't close his forms. sigh.

Comment: My mistake --- In my code, I did in fact close the form. Just was sloppy with the cut/paste job here. Please help.

Comment: @user1364628 Oops, I don't know how I missed this. Your problem is very evident. See my updated answer. As you are new to SO, I also ask that you accept my answer if it is the solution to your issue. I am confident that it is.